# How to use iterated MySQL queries and form a json encoded result?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json, codeigniter

I have a problem when executing multiple SQL into an array and then display to JSON data, this is my code:

```
$sql0="SELECT id,
              company_id,
              class_name
       FROM cc_class_room
       WHERE company_id='CO191125310002'";

$res=$this->db->query($sql0);
$data=$res->result_array();

$i=0;

foreach($data as $row ) {
    $sql1="SELECT COUNT(user_id) member FROM cc_class_room_user WHERE class_id='".$row['company_id']."' GROUP BY class_id";
    $res1=$this->db->query($sql1);

    $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row['id'];
    $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array("company_id"=>$row['company_id'],"class_name"=>$row['class_name'],"member"=>$row['member']);
    $i++;
}

return json_encode($responce);
```

When I did this I got an error:

> Undefined index: member

The second SQL can't execute, how do I execute sql to array, without join/union the SQL? This is display JSON that I want [image: json]

This is an application built on CodeIgniter.

Comment: Don't do two queries in the first place. Use a single `JOIN` query.

Comment: Why "without union/join of the SQL"?

Comment: There will surely be a duplicate to show how to JOIN, GROUP BY, AND COUNT().

Comment: @barmar , sorry this is because my collage want this, i try subquery but he want this metode , he say this is more efficient then query , sorry  this is 
unreasonable reasons

Comment: @LutfiMiftahudin is your application built on any popular frameworks?  For instance, this might be a CodeIgniter script.

Comment: @mickmackusa yes , i use CI

Comment: @LutfiMiftahudin If you take the time to create a db-fiddle demo link for me (I'll just need the two tables with a handful of related rows in each table to provide me a testing environment), then I will post an answer to show you how to write a professional-grade CodeIgniter script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't fetched the `member` value from the second query. You need to fetch that into a different array so you can add it to your output data:

```
foreach($data as $row ) {
    $sql1="SELECT COUNT(user_id) member FROM cc_class_room_user WHERE class_id='".$row['company_id']."'";
    $res1=$this->db->query($sql1);
    $row1=$res1->result_array();
    $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row['id'];
    $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array("company_id"=>$row['company_id'],"class_name"=>$row['class_name'],"member"=>$row1[0]['member']);
    $i++;
}
```

Note that you don't need to use a counter in your loop, you can put all the data together in an array and push it in one line:

```
$responce[] = array('id' => $row['id'],
                    'cell' => array("company_id" => $row['company_id'],
                                    "class_name"=>$row['class_name'],
                                     "member"=>$row1[0]['member']
                                   )
                    );
```

Comment: @Lutfi Nick is going to next explain how running iterated queries is not ideal.

Comment: @Nick thanks for helping , but this give me an error Undefined offset: 0

Comment: @LutfiMiftahudin did you change `$row` to `$row1` for that reference?

Comment: You don't need `GROUP BY class_id` since the query is just for a single `class_id`.

Comment: @mickmackusa the group by column doesn't need to be declared. I guess this could be written as a `JOIN` with a subquery...

Comment: @Nick ya the [0] give me an error Undefined offset: 0, when i remove that i got an error again Undefined index: member

Comment: @Barmar indeed. I just copied that from OPs code but will fix.

Comment: @LutfiMiftahudin what do you get if you `var_dump($row1)`?

Comment: In fact, you need to get rid of `GROUP BY` if you want to get a zero count for classes that aren't found.

Comment: @LutfiMiftahudin please note the changes to the `$sql1` query, that might be causing your undefined offset issue.

Comment: @Nick The OP commented above that he's not allowed to use a join.

Comment: @Barmar I know, that's why I just used their existing code. I was just responding to mickmackusa's comment about running iterated queries.

Comment: @Nick i try check the query , the problem maybe from my query , i try  remove "group by" it show no error but the data still wrong on member give me "0" value, but your metode work perfectly , i will try fix my second query first

Comment: @LutfiMiftahudin as long as you are happy... removing the `group by` is necessary to ensure you do get a result when there are no `user_id` values associated with a given `class_id`. If you're getting `0` as a result maybe there's no data in the table for that `company_id`? Perhaps you should actually be using `$row['id']` instead? that would seem more likely to be a value which would match with a `class_id` column.

Comment: @Nick yep wrong fromat i must call an id , not a company id , thanks u so much

Comment: @Nick please demonstrate how push the new data into the responce->rows array without using `$i`.  A counter is unnecessary here.

Comment: @LutfiMiftahudin note you can simplify the loop code to remove the counter. See my edit.

Comment: @Nick look more simple :) , let me try this too , thanks for suggestion sir :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but this is important to share...

About your error, it looks like you forgot to declare the result set in the loop like you did for the `$data` before the loop.

```
$res1=$this->db->query($sql1);  // $res1 is never used again!
```

You could have just written the count directly into your new data structure like this:

```
'member' => $res1->getRowArray['member']
```

---

You should not be making iterated trips to the server when you can do all of the work in a single trip.  You can use a subquery in the SELECT clause -- this will make just as many individual queries on the tables as in your original script, but this does it all in one trip.  This is better practice and your teacher should not be telling you otherwise.

Also, since you are scripting your application in CodeIgniter, you should fully embrace the active record syntax.  If your incoming `company_id` value is user-supplied, then the following snippet will actually help you to write a stable, secure, and portable query.

Raw MySQL SELECT with subquery: ([db-fiddle.com demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sSAhF2ZpYuzwTX8UTweEzu/0))

```
SELECT id,
       class_name,
       (SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM cc_class_room_user
        WHERE class_id = company_id) AS members
FROM cc_class_room
WHERE company_id = 'CO191125310002'
```

SELECT with subquery via CodeIgniter's Active Record:
(I have tested this locally to be successful/trustworthy)

```
$companyId = 'CO191125310002';

$subquery = $this->db
    ->select('COUNT(1)')
    ->from('cc_class_room_user')
    ->where('class_id = company_id')
    ->get_compiled_select();

$resultSet = $this->db
    ->select("id, class_name, ({$subquery}) AS members")
    ->from('cc_class_room')
    ->where('company_id', $companyId)
    ->get()
    ->result_array();
```

I'll also say that there may be better alternative queries which can be executed, but to be completely confident, I'd need to have access to your table schema to run some tests.

---

No matter which way you choose to query the database, the preparation of your results, IMO, is most cleanly written like this:

```
$results = [];
foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
    $results[] = [
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'cell' => [
            'company_id' => $companyId,  // no reason to query for what you already know
            'class_name' => $row['class_name'],
            'members' => $row['members'],  // I am using plural because it makes better sense for a counted value
        ],
    ];
}
return json_encode(['rows' => $results], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: sorry for late respon, thanks for give me this starting pack, thanks u so much for ur teaching, gonna use this standar, my friend say to use this standar code for ci